# Do wee need a lock for uint64_t in single writer multi-reader situation?

Tags: c++, c, concurrency

```
class Foo {
public:
    void set(uint64_t new_var) { var_ = new_var; }
    uint64_t get() { return var_; }
private:
    uint64_t var_;
};
```

Is there necessary need a lock in `set` and `get` if one writer multi-reader?

Comment: It depends on the platform the code is running on, but you can use `std::atomic<uint64_t>` to be on the safe side.

Comment: No variable in C can be assumed to have atomic access unless declared `_Atomic`. CPU data width doesn't matter, the number of writers doesn't matter. If the write occurs in several instructions (such as "load register from stack", "write value to register") and get interrupted half-ways, then you have a race condition bug. In some situations this might only cause incorrect timing bugs, in other situations corrupt data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there necessary need a lock in `set` and `get` if one writer multi-reader?*

You don't necessarily need a *lock*, but you **need** *synchronization*, which can be achieved either by locking a ***mutex*** or simply declaring the variable ***atomic***.

In C++:   `std::atomic<uint64_t> var_;`

In C: `_Atomic uint64_t var_;`

Regardless of the data type, in both C and C++ languages every variable accessed concurrently when there is at least one writer involved, requires *synchronization*.

This has to do with the way the compiler orders instructions when generating code; in the absence of synchronization, as per the [*as-if* rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule), the compiler is allowed to assume each thread is executed in isolation, and reorder variable accesses any way it sees fit. Unsynchronized access immediately lands the program in the realm of *undefined behavior* as it becomes impossible to predict the outcome. For example, the variable can be optimized into a CPU register, and two threads will never notice it changing at all, or it may be written to memory at a different time in the program.

In addition, on many CPU architectures (not counting x86) 64-bit reads/writes are actually not atomic. So even if the code happens to be laid out favorably, it may still not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary.
Besides of platform restrictions (see comment), your uint64_t can be unaligned: the reading can request 2 operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    void set(uint64_t new_var) { var_ = new_var; }
    uint64_t get() { return var_; }

private:
    uint64_t var_;
};

int main()
{
    Foo v1; v1.set(0);
    uint64_t v2 = 0;

    std::vector<std::future<void>> ret_1;
    ret_1.reserve(10);
    std::vector<std::future<void>> ret_2;
    ret_2.reserve(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ret_1.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10'000; j++)
                v1.set(v1.get() + 1ul);
        }));
        ret_2.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() { 
            for (int j = 0; j < 10'000; j++)
                v2+=1ul; 
        }));
    }

    for(auto& f : ret_1)
        f.wait();

    for(auto& f : ret_2)
        f.wait();

    // Expected in both examples: 10'000 * 10 = 100'000
    std::cout << "Foo: " << v1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "uint64_t: " << v2 << std::endl;

}
```

Expectred results is 100'000 but this is output:

```
raidg@Papuga:~$ c++ -o main main.cpp -lpthread
raidg@Papuga:~$ ./main 
Foo: 26257
uint64_t: 32825
```

Because there is no sync between them